# Avatar is saved to MongoDB but no success message and rendering of avatar in component, using React and Multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api, multer

Depending on your viewpoint, I was able to get the most important part of getting a Avatar/Image in an app...pushing to the database (MongoDB in my case, Also the image gets added to my server folder).

However what I can't get working is the success modal to fire or the rendering of the image on the page, which is strange as the `response.status === 200` and `response.ok === true`? I am using [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) in Express. (I am using fetch).

This is my ImageLoader component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ImageUploader.css';
import Modal from '../Modal/MyModal.jsx'

import DefaultImg from '../../static/profile-avatars/assets/default-img.jpg';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { modalStateOn, modalStateOff } from '../../store/index'

    const API_URL = "http://localhost:8016";

class ImageUploader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      multerImage: DefaultImg,
    }
  }

  setDefaultImage(uploadType) {
    if (uploadType === "multer") {
      this.setState({
        multerImage: DefaultImg
      });
     }
    }

  uploadImage(e, method) {
   var { history, isLoggedIn, modalActive, modalStateOn, modalStateOff  } = this.props

    let imageObj = {};

    if (method === "multer") {

      let imageFormObj = new FormData();

      imageFormObj.append("imageName", "multer-image-" + Date.now());
      imageFormObj.append("imageData", e.target.files[0]);

      // stores a readable instance of
      // the image being uploaded using multer
      this.setState({
        multerImage: window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
      });

     return window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/images/uploadmulter', {
       method: 'POST',
        // body: e.target.files[0]
        body: imageFormObj
      })
       .then((response) => {
         console.log("response ", response);
         this.setDefaultImage("multer");
        return (
         <>
          {response.ok && <Modal
           isAlertModal={true}
           history={history}
           affirmativeUsed="Yes"
           message="Image has been successfully uploaded!"
           isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
           modalActive={true}
           modalStateOn={modalStateOn}
           modalStateOff={modalStateOff}></Modal>}
         </>
        )

        })
       .then((data) => {
        console.log("data ", data);

        this.setDefaultImage("multer");

       })
      .catch(error => {
       this.setDefaultImage("multer");
       console.log("error ", error);

      })

     }
  } // end upload function

  render() {
   // console.log("uploadImage function this.props ", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <h3 className="main-heading">Image Upload App</h3>

        <div className="image-container">
          <div className="process">
            <h4 className="process__heading">Process: Using Multer</h4>
            <p className="process__details">Upload image to a node server, connected to a MongoDB database, with the help of multer</p>
           <form action="/uploadmulter" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" >
              <input type="file" name="avatar" className="process__upload-btn" onChange={(e) => this.uploadImage(e, "multer")} />
              <img src={this.state.multerImage} alt="upload-image" className="process__image" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { isLoggedIn, modalActive } = state
 return { isLoggedIn, modalActive }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ modalStateOn, modalStateOff }, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageUploader)
```

And this is the route on my express server `server/images/index.js`:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Image = require('../models/Image');
var multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){
   cb(null, './server/uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
   cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
  }
})

var fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
 if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
  cb(null, true);
 } else {
  // rejects storing a file
  cb(null, false)
 }
}

var upload = multer({
 storage: storage,
 limits : {
  fileSize : 1024 * 1024 * 5
 },
 fileFilter: fileFilter
})

router.route('/uploadmulter')
 .post(upload.single('imageData'), (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('req.body', req.body);
   var newImage = new Image({
    imageName: req.body.imageName,
    imageData : req.file.path
   })

   newImage.save()
   .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      document:result
    })
   })
   .catch(err=> next(err))
  });

  module.exports = router
```

So to reiterate why doesn't the image render and modal fire when the response is true or 200?